# winston logger not serializing mongodb.ObjectID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, winston

I want to finally move away from console.log as a logging system and have been looking into both winston and bunyan.  I have a slight preference for winston as for now I want human readable logs in longentries, and bunyan is a bit too chatty with all the extra fields.

winston is great except that it doesn't properly serialize mongo database ids.

If I do something like this:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var winston = require('winston');
winston.info(new ObjectId());
```

This is what gets written to stdout:

> info:  _bsontype=ObjectID, id=Tø½þjÍrßgK

Sometimes I just want to dump an entire mongoose document to the log.  I don't want to have to call .toString() on all my object ids?

Has anyone been able to work around this  problematic scenario in winston?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a format specifier most probably.

You can do something like this:

`winston.info('%j', new ObjectId());`

You can read about format specifiers here http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format

Answer (score 0):

In the end I wrapped the winston logging methods in a function that just applied the node format utility with the default format to all the arguments.  Works a treat so far:

```
var util = require('util');
var winston = require('winston');


var fixWinstonParams = function (fn) {
    return function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            arguments[i] = util.format( arguments[i]);
        }
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};


['info', 'error', 'debug', 'warn'].map(function(each){
    winston[each] = fixWinstonParams( winston[each])
});
```